# PHP Image Scraper only selected images

Tags: php, dom

im trying to build a simple image scraper to scrap certain images from a site how ever what i have so far scrapes all the images

```
<?php
$url = "http://www.techbuy.com.au/";
$html = file_get_contents('http://www.techbuy.com.au/');
$dom = new domDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$images = $dom->getElementsByTagName('img');
foreach ($images as $image)
{
$fimage =  $image->getAttribute('src');
echo "<img src='$url" . "$fimage' ></img>";
}
?>
```

how can i make it say scrap the second image and leave the rest

Comment: You need grab only second image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php
$url = "http://www.techbuy.com.au/";
$html = file_get_contents('http://www.techbuy.com.au/');
$dom = new domDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$images = $dom->getElementsByTagName('img');

foreach ($images as $key => $image)
{
    if ($key === 1) {
        $fimage =  $image->getAttribute('src');
        echo "<img src='$url" . "$fimage' ></img>";
    }
}
?>
```

Grabs the second image.

Comment: maybe add a break in the if statement. it really is unnecessary to keep looping after you found the image

Answer (score 2):

```
if ($images->length >= 2) { $src = $images->item(1)->getAttribute("src"); }
```